# This program is intended to find the maximum in the list. Where is the code wrong? Try :Enter the numbers: 1,99,133

Tags: python-3.x

```
a = input("Enter the numbers: ").split(",")
print(a)
max = a[0]
for i in a:
    if i > max:
        max = i
print(max)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing strings, not integers. You should convert the items to integers before comparing them. For example:

```
a = input("Enter the numbers: ").split(",")
print(a)
max = a[0]
for i in a:
    if int(i) > int(max):
        max = i
print(max)
```